# how can i know the javascript application code flow in between the js files

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

are there any UI tools to know for project java script UI code navigation in between all the js files.how can i get all the js code functional flow at a glance.

Comment: What specifically are you asking for?  An IDE?  A debugger?  Your browser's development tools are pretty solid, but it sounds like you're talking about some sort of code analysis.

Comment: Can you explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google web developer tool to see the code flow. 
If you know the entry point to the code, put a break point at that line and run it.

Then click F10 to go to the next execution point of the code.